# Using join to return multiple data cells from the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a join to pull data from some tables. for 2 of the columns of data needed from the join query are in the same column on the table.

Here is what I have right now:

```
SELECT [contract_member_brg_attr].field_id,
       [contract_member_brg_attr].attr_val AS 'properties',
       [contract_attr].attr_val            AS 'contract_number',
       [contract_attr].attr_val            AS 'supplier_number'
FROM   [contract_member_brg_attr]
       INNER JOIN [contract_member_brg]
               ON [contract_member_brg_attr].item_id =
                  [contract_member_brg].item_id
       INNER JOIN [contract_attr]
               ON [contract_attr].item_id =
                  [contract_member_brg].[contract_item_id]
                  AND [contract_attr].field_id = 413
```

This is returning the following.

[image]

As you can see the last 2 rows being returned are the same because they come from the same column and I am only filtering by one of them (413).

Here is where it's pulling from():

[image]

I need the values from 413 AND 234 in the 2nd column.

When I try to add that I want to filter by 234(`OR [CONTRACT_ATTR].field_id = 234`) also everything breaks:

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Actually none of those rows are the same. They are all different. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Are you wanting data items from 2 rows to appear as 2 separate columns in your end result? You have only used the `[contract_attr]` table once. `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` to it again using an alias to get the 2nd attribute.

Comment: @SeanLange In the 2nd image do you see 12/234/A180 and 12/413/b5v5b5b5bb5? I want both of those to come in as columns from the join query.

Comment: @mheptinstall Yes, that is what I am trying to do. Could you show what you mean with the new JOINs?

Comment: If you could post some ddl and sample data this would be a LOT easier to understand. From the two rows you say you want as a single row I don't see anything that indicates those two rows are somehow related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the same table by giving it an alias in this example I have called it `[other_contract_attr]` and restricting the results to the `field_id` of 234.

```
SELECT [contract_member_brg_attr].field_id,
       [contract_member_brg_attr].attr_val AS 'properties',
       [contract_attr].attr_val            AS 'contract_number',
       [other_contract_attr].attr_val            AS 'supplier_number'
FROM   [contract_member_brg_attr]
       INNER JOIN [contract_member_brg]
               ON [contract_member_brg_attr].item_id =
                  [contract_member_brg].item_id
       INNER JOIN [contract_attr]
               ON [contract_attr].item_id =
                  [contract_member_brg].[contract_item_id]
                  AND [contract_attr].field_id = 413
    INNER JOIN [contract_attr] AS [other_contract_attr]
               ON [other_contract_attr].item_id =
                  [contract_member_brg].[contract_item_id]
                  AND [other_contract_attr].field_id = 234
```

However, it looks like you are trying to `PIVOT` rows into columns, if you are wanting to return multiple rows into columns from the same table it would be better to `PIVOT` your values like so and JOIN to that instead:

```
SELECT
[item_id],
MAX(CASE WHEN [field_id] = 413
    THEN [attr_val]
END) AS [413_val],
MAX(CASE WHEN [field_id] = 234
    THEN [attr_val]
END) AS [234_val],

FROM
[contract_attr]

GROUP BY
[item_id]
```

Comment: Perfect, I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to your question but it is too long for a comment. If you used aliases in your queries they would a LOT easier to read and maintain. Here is what your query would look like just by using aliases instead of those really long table names over and over.

```
SELECT mba.field_id,
       mba.attr_val AS 'properties',
       ca.attr_val AS 'contract_number',
       ca.attr_val AS 'supplier_number'
FROM   contract_member_brg_attr mba
       INNER JOIN contract_member_brg mb
               ON mba.item_id =
                  mb.item_id
       INNER JOIN contract_attr ca
               ON ca.item_id =
                  mb.contract_item_id
                  AND ca.field_id = 413
```

Comment: Cool beans.. :D

Comment: Definitely more developer friendly. :P